# quadratic probing hash table

Tags: java, hashtable, quadratic-probing

Hellow, For some off reason I cannot get my hash table to fill with the items and keys when I insert. It seems like it is being added when run through the driver, but nothing is stored, and there are absolutely no error messages.
I am suppose to create a hash table that utilizes quadratic probing. I am suppose to count the number of transversals which cannot be > 20.

Here is the code:

```
public class HashTable {
    String[] table;
    String[] keys;
    int currentSize, maxSize, numOfEntries;
    int traverse = 0;
    double capacity;    

public HashTable(int size, double load){
    if(size <= 0){
        System.out.println("Size must be greater then 0");
    }
    else if(load < 0 || load > 1){
        System.out.println("Load must be between 0 and 1. EX: 0.75");
    }else{
        this.currentSize = 0;
        table = new String[size];
        keys = new String[size];
        this.capacity = load * size;
        this.maxSize = size;
    }
}

public int hash(String num){
    return (2 * Integer.parseInt(num) + 5) % table.length;
}

public int getLength(){
    return table.length;
}

public int getMaxSize(){
    return maxSize;
}

public int probe(String num){
    int temp = hash(num);
    int calc = 0;
    numOfEntries = 0;

        while(table[temp] != null){
            traverse++;
            temp = (int)((temp + (float)calc/2 + (float) (calc * calc)) % maxSize);
            calc++;
            numOfEntries++;
        }

    if(traverse >= 20){
        System.out.println("Insert Failed : Reached 20 Traversal Limit!");
        return 20;
    }

    return temp;
}

public void resize(){
    String [] tempTable = table;
    if(table.length >= capacity){
        table = new String[tempTable.length * 2];
        for(int i = 0; i < tempTable.length; i++){
            if(tempTable[i] != null){
                insert(tempTable[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void insert(String num){
    int temp = probe(num);
    table[temp] = num;
    currentSize++;

    if(currentSize >= capacity){
        resize();
    }

}


public String searchKey(String key){
    String temp = "";
    numOfEntries = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
        if(key == keys[i]){
            temp = table[i];
            numOfEntries++;
            break;
        }
        numOfEntries++;

    }

    if(temp == ""){
        System.out.println("No items that match that key!");
    }
    return temp;
}

public int numOfEntries(){
    return numOfEntries;
}

public void print(){
System.out.println("Key\t:\tValue");
for(int i = 0; i < table.length; i++){
    if(keys[i] != null){
        System.out.println(keys[i] + "\t:\t" + table[i]);
    }
}
    System.out.println();
}
```

}

Here is the Driver:

```
import java.util.*;
public class HashTableDriver {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Table Size:\t");
    int size = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Load Factor (Between 0 and 1");
    double load = scan.nextDouble();



    int temp = 0;
    HashTable table = new HashTable(size,load);
    System.out.println(table.getLength());
    System.out.println(table.getMaxSize());


    while(temp != 4){
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("i)(1) Insert an item to the Hash Table" +
                "\nii)(2) Search A Specific Key" +
                "\niii)(3) Display the Table" +
                "\nvii)(4) Quit");
        String input = scan.next();

        switch(input){
        case "1":
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Enter value to add to table");
            String desKey1 = scan.next();
            table.insert(desKey1);
            continue;
        case "2":
            System.out.println("Please enter specific key desired:\t");
            String desKey2 = scan.next();
            if(table.searchKey(desKey2).equals(desKey2)){
                System.out.println("Key Found");
                System.out.println("Number of cells accessed:\t" + table.numOfEntries());
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Key Not Found");
            }
            continue;
        case "3":
            table.print();
            continue;
        case "4":
            temp = 4;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried to debug this code?

Comment: Yes I have. Nothing is showing in the debugger either. It is like the program runs perfectly fine, but nothing is stored.........

Comment: Try to insert a breakpoint inside insert() method, examine how it works step-by-step, and locate some unexplainable behavior of the java machine and/or its core libraries and post here the exact line where some illogical thing is having place. Take note that in Java you're supposed to compare strings with String.equals method because operator == returns true if and only if you're comparing a String with itself, otherwise it always returns false, even if both string's contents are identical.

Comment: Now I am getting an error with my search method. It says that there is a null pointer exception on the like:

Comment: Strings in Java are objects. Objects passed by reference. References can be null, it means that reference does not reference anything. Of course you can't invoke `str.equals(otherString)` if the `str` is a null reference. The `otherString` can be null, `equals(otherString)` will return false in this case. Use something like `if (str != null && str.equals(otherString) ) {}`

Comment: maybe you didn't mean to change the calc variable in your quadratic probe() method during probing.  I thought for quadratic probing c1 and c2 were constants that didn't change during the probing.  You can try different c1 and c2 but they must remain same during the call to probe?